# Mix str_replace and regex?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I want to replace a string such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="12345" />
```

but the problem I have is that the values value (12345) is different everytime so how can I do what I'm trying to do? ..I'm guessing regex' but havent a clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\<input type="hidden" name="id" value="[0-9]+" \/\>/is', '', $source)
```